# Windows 10 pro wifi not working even after few deletion from registry (as instructed)

Tags: wireless-networking, drivers, windows-10-upgrade, wifi-driver, mode

Just upgraded from windows 7 to windows 10 pro and now my wifi doesn't seems to be working.

So, as instructed from microsoft/support, that few commands will ease out from this issue. So i did start the command prompt (admin) and keyed `reg delete HKCR\CLSID{988248f3-a1ad-49bf-9170-676cbbc36ba3} /va /f`, but it says "the system was unable to find the specific registery key or value" and when i rollback and search it manually through regedit, I was unable to find the registry key too.

Also when I use `netcfg -v -u dni-dne`, it says **dni-dne is not installed**.

Anyone HELP?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem as well.

Chances are, your WiFi drivers are incompatible with Windows 10. I'd check online to see if your manufacturer has released a compatible driver, or get on the phone with tech support to see if they can direct you to the correct driver downloads. You will need to load the driver installer onto a flash drive from a separate computer though.

If this doesn't work, and there are no compatible network drivers for your laptop, the only option you really have is to roll back to Windows 7.

Comment: Currently using HP pro laptop and the current drivers are compatible with windows 10.  Drivers were installed from registered site of HP and of course it had been directed correctly. Will need to load drivers as instructed and will let me come up if any issues may arise.  Thanks for the effort Eathan.